# Why do copied dictionaries point to the same directory but lists don't?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Can someone tell me why when you copy dictionaries they both point to the same directory, so that a change to one effects the other, but this is not the case for lists?

I am interested in the logic behind why they would set up the dictionary one way, and lists another. It's confusing and if I know the reason behind it I will probably remember.

```
dict = {'Dog' : 'der Hund' , 'Cat' : 'die Katze' , 'Bird' : 'der Vogel'}
otherdict = dict
dict.clear()
print otherdict
```

Which results in otherdict = {}.So both dicts are pointing to the same directory. But this isn't the case for lists.

```
list = ['one' , 'two' , 'three']
newlist = list
list = list + ['four']
print newlist
```

newlist still holds on to the old list. So they are not pointing to the same directory. I am wanting to know the rationale behind the reasons why they are different?

Comment: Please show code which demonstrates the behavior you're asking about.

Comment: Possibly you are confusing lists with tuples. Show us what you are doing

Comment: Your dictionary example has two assigns (`=`) while your list has three.  There's the difference right there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some code with similar intent to yours will show that changes to one list do affect other references.

```
>>> list = ['one' , 'two' , 'three']
>>> newlist = list
>>> list.append('four')
>>> print newlist
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

That is the closest analogy to your dictionary code. You call a method on the original object.

The difference is that with your code you used a separate plus and assignment operator

```
list = list + ['four']
```

This is two separate operations. First the interpreter evaluates the expression `list + ['four']`. It *must* put the result of that computation in a new list object, because it does not anticipate that you will assign the result back to list. If you had said `other_list = list + ['four']`, you would have been very annoyed if list were modified.

Now there is a new object, containing the result of `list + ['four']`. That new object is assigned to list. list is now a reference to the new object, whereas newlist remains a reference to the old object.

Even this is different

```
list += ['four']
```

The += has the meaning for mutable object that it will modify the object in place.

Answer (score 4):

Your two cases are doing different things to the objects you're copying, that's why you're seeing different results.

First off, you're not really copying them. Your simply making new "references" or (in more Pythonic terms) binding new names to the same objects.

With the dictionary, you're calling `dict.clear`, which discards all the contents. This modifies the existing object, so you see the results through both of the references you have to it.

With the list, you're rebinding one of the names to a new list. This new list is not the same as the old list, which remains unmodified.

You could recreate the behavior of your dictionary code with the lists if you want. A slice assignment is one way to modify a whole list at once:

```
old_list[:] = [] # empties the list in place
```

One addendum, unrelated to the main issue above: It's a very bad idea to use names like `dict` and `list` as variables in your own code. That's because those are the names of the builtin Python dictionary and list types. By using the same names, you shadow the built in ones, which can lead to confusing bugs.

Comment: Thanks I read further and found that the lists do actually show the same behaviour as the dictionaries. But then I couldn't figure out why my example wasn't doing it. But now I see what I did wrong I created a new list, I didn't amend it! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In your dictionary example, you've created a dictionary and store it in `dict`. You then store the same reference in `otherdict`. Now both *`dict` and `otherdict` point to the same dictionary**. Then you call `dict.clear()`. This clears the dictionary that both `dict` and `otherdict` point to.

In your list example, you've created a list and store it in `list`. You then store the same reference in `otherlist`. **Then you create a new list** consisting of the elements of `list` and another element and **store the *new* list** in `list`. You did not modify the original list you created. You created a new list and changed what `list` pointed to.

You can get your list example to show the same behavior as the dictionary example by using `list.append('four')` rather than `list = list + ['four']`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
>>> d = {'test1': 1, 'test2': 2}
>>> new_d = d
>>> new_d['test3'] = 3
>>> new_d
{'test1': 1, 'test3': 3, 'test2': 2}
>>> d # copied over
{'test1': 1, 'test3': 3, 'test2': 2}
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> new_lst = lst
>>> new_lst.append(5)
>>> new_lst
[1, 2, 3, 5]
>>> lst # copied over
[1, 2, 3, 5]
>>> new_lst += [5]
>>> lst # copied over
[1, 2, 3, 5, 5]
>>> my_tuple = (1, 2, 3)
>>> new_my_tuple = my_tuple
>>> new_my_tuple += (5,)
>>> new_my_tuple
(1, 2, 3, 5)
>>> my_tuple # immutable, so it is not affected by new_my_tuple
(1, 2, 3)
```

Lists DO pass reference, not the object themselves. Most (hesitant on saying all) mutable (can be changed, such as lists and dictionaries) objects pass references, whereas immutable (cannot be changed, such as tuples) objects pass the object themselves.